# Swift - post requests with alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm having a little trouble with Alamofire. I have server functions that successfully working on android devices. Everything works fine and all data working without problems. But on iOS everytime when I send post request with more than 2 parameters I got an error from server so I can't post data. I tried to put post as a string in custom encoding, because when I put parameters into Alamofire.request method I also got an error but then server response is "error in unexeption handler". So I changed all JSON into string thanks to String extension, then I change every "[" and "]" to "{", "}", but still I can't save data to server.

**Encoded Dictionary and changed into JSON in Swift looks like this:**

> calls=%7B%220%22%3A%7B%22call%5Fdate%22%3A%222018%2D06%2D27%2B11%3A30%3A46%22%2C%22number%22%3A%22462462432%22%2C%22sms%22%3A%220%22%2C%22duration%22%3A%220%22%2C%22type%22%3A211%7D%7D

**Dictionary in Swift**

```
["calls": ["0": ["call_date": "2018-06-27+11:49:18", "number": "56262621", "sms": "0", "duration": "0", "type": 211]]]
```

On the other hand same application on Android works perfect with the same data.

**Encoded JSON in Java looks like this:**

> calls=%7B%220%22%3A%7B%22number%22%3A%22852486258965%22%2C%22duration%22%3A%220%22%2C%22type%22%3A211%2C%22call_date%22%3A%222018-06-27+11%3A53%3A53%22%2C%22sms%22%3A%220%22%7D%7D

**JSON in Java**

```
{"calls":{"0":{"number":"852486258965","duration":"0","type":211,"call_date":"2018-06-27 11:53:53","sms":"0"}}}
```

Why in Android App everything works but on iOS it doesn't work at all? Does anyone have an idea for that?

**Function in Swift**

```
func sendStoreCalls(parameters: Dictionary<Int, Dictionary<String, Any>>) {

        var params: Parameters = [:]
        var par: Parameters = [:]
        var pa: [String:Any] = [:]
        var i = 0
        for (_, param) in parameters {
            if param["isSend"] as! Int == 0 {
                par["duration"] = param["callTime"]
                par["sms"] = "0"
                let callDate: String = param["callDate"] as! String
                par["type"] = param["callType"]
                par["call_date"] = callDate.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+", options: .literal, range: nil)
                if param["callNumber"] as! String != "" {
                    par["number"] = param["callNumber"]
                }
                params[String(i)] = par
                i += 1
            }
        }

        pa["calls"] = params

        let token: String = SharedPreferences.getPrefToken()!

        let bufferedParams = pa.queryParameters

        let transformedPar = bufferedParams.replacingOccurrences(of: "%5B", with: "%7B", options: .literal, range: nil).replacingOccurrences(of: "%5D", with: "%7D", options: .literal, range: nil)

        let trn = transformedPar.replacingOccurrences(of: "%C2A0", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil).replacingOccurrences(of: "%20", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)

        let url = "https://url.com?api_token=\(token)"

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, encoding: JSONStringArrayEncoding.init(string: trn))
            .responseJSON {
                response in
                print(NSString(data: (response.request?.httpBody)!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    print(json["message"].rawString()!)
                case .failure(let error):
                    if let data = response.data {
                        print("ERROR!!!")
                        print(String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
                    }
                    print(error)
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method with/without encoding parameter as well as by adding/Removing header ["Content-Type":"application/json"]

```
func request(_ method: HTTPMethod
    , _ URLString: String
    , parameters: [String : AnyObject]? = [:]
    , headers: [String : String]? = [:]
    , onView: UIView?, vc: UIViewController, completion:@escaping (Any?) -> Void
    , failure: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {


    Alamofire.request(URLString, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                completion(response.result.value!)
            case .failure(let error):
                failure(error)
                guard error.localizedDescription == JSON_COULDNOT_SERIALISED else {
                    AppUtil().showMessage((error.localizedDescription), messageTitle: EMPTY_STRING, buttonTitle: OK, vc: vc)
                    return
                }
                //                    AppUtil.showMessage(SOMETHING_WNET_WRONG, messageTitle: EMPTY_STRING, buttonTitle: OK)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You helped me a lot. When I added: parameters: pa, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: ["Content-Type":"application/json"], to my Alamofire.request I finally got successful response! Thanks for help.